# unable to call click event in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the html code:

```
 <input type="button" id="abc" name="TechSupport_PartsOrder" value="Open Editor" />
```

Below is the JQuery Code:

```
$('#abc').click(function () {
alert('x');
});
```

Now when i put the above JQuery code to JS file it does not work, while when i put the same in page it works fine. Why this is happening i don't knw.

And if i call the function onclick of button like this:

```
 <input type="button" id="abc" name="TechSupport_PartsOrder" onclick="abc()" value="Open Editor" />
```

JQuery:

```
function abc()
{
 alert('x');
}
```

it works well..

Comment: "Now when i put the above JQuery code to JS file it does not work". So what error(s) do you get in the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the code in a `ready` handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#abc').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: isn't that just wrapping it in an anonymous function?

Comment: @thescientist: Yes, but then it's passing it as an argument to the `$` function, which will call the passed function once the DOM has loaded.

Comment: very cool.  good to know.  So using that syntax is kind of like adding events to the queue that will be executed upon DOM load (ready)?

Comment: @thescientist: Yes. `$(someFunction)` is the same as `$(document).ready(someFunction)`.

Comment: ooohh... I see what you mean.  Cool!  How did you find that out?  Is it int the documentation, or just fiddling around?

Comment: @thescientist: It's [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Comment: doh, haha.  yup, there it is!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that the event handler is getting defined *after* the DOM has loaded?  This is why jquery recommends putting all your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  //XXX code goes here
});
```

you're event handler is probably try to be assigned before the element has been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: it's essentially the same as using window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Does the following solve the problem?

```
$(function(){
  $('#abc').click(function () {
    alert('x');
  });  
})
```

Your code may be getting called before '#abc' has been added to the DOM